# Regex to match single word without prefix or suffix

Tags: python, regex, eclipse

I am trying to match a single word in my .py files in Eclipse IDE. Using the file search function, I am trying to match the following:

```
   return => true (tabbed indent)
return => true

#return => false
 return => false (space prefix)
"return" => false
```

EDIT:
I've used the following regex but it returns following false positives, matches that should be *excluded*: `\b(return)\b`.

```
word1 return word2
#return
```

Should find the word "return" by itself and/or just 1 TAB in front

Comment: Can you give examples of some of the false positives that it's returning? Is everything in the example text you provided an intentional match?

Comment: Have you tried using an online regex tester like regex101.com??  You want to match ```return``` at the start of the string or preceded by a tab and always a whitespace following.

Comment: @CAustin I've added the false positives I keep matching that should be excluded in my EDIT. Yes only the true results are the ones I want matched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

> **^\t*return**

You can test your regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/fHM4Eu/3/)

Comment: with a multiline flag if searching the entire file - not line by line

Comment: Worked best for my use case, found all the matches I was looking for. Formatting in Eclipse caused other regex posted to return no results

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^\t?(return)$
```

Where `^` means start of string, and `$` means end of string.